# my kubernetes cluster does not scale down

Tags: kubernetes

I have kuberentes cluster. One master and one worker.
I install metric-server for auto scaling and then i run stress test

```
$ kubectl run autoscale-test --image=ubuntu:16.04 --requests=cpu=1000m --command sleep 1800
deployment "autoscale-test" created
$ kubectl autoscale deployment autoscale-test --cpu-percent=25 --min=1 --max=5
deployment "autoscale-test" autoscaled
$ kubectl get hpa
NAME             REFERENCE                   TARGETS    MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
autoscale-test   Deployment/autoscale-test   0% / 25%   1         5         1          1m
$ kubectl get pod
NAME                              READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
autoscale-test-59d66dcbf7-9fqr8   1/1       Running   0          9m
kubectl exec autoscale-test-59d66dcbf7-9fqr8 -- apt-get update
kubectl exec autoscale-test-59d66dcbf7-9fqr8 -- apt-get install stress

$ kubectl exec autoscale-test-59d66dcbf7-9fqr8 -- stress --cpu 2 --timeout 600s &
stress: info: [227] dispatching hogs: 2 cpu, 0 io, 0 vm, 0 hdd
```

everything works fine and the pod was auto scaled but after that the pod that was created by autoscale is still running and they do not terminate after the stress test
the hpa shows that the 0% of cpu is in use but the 5 autoscaled pod still running

```
#kubectl get hpa
NAME             REFERENCE                   TARGETS   MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
autoscale-test   Deployment/autoscale-test   0%/25%    1         5         5          74m

#kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default       autoscale-test-8f4d84bbf-7ddjw   1/1     Running   0          61m
default       autoscale-test-8f4d84bbf-bmr59   1/1     Running   0          61m
default       autoscale-test-8f4d84bbf-cxt26   1/1     Running   0          61m
default       autoscale-test-8f4d84bbf-x9jws   1/1     Running   0          61m
default       autoscale-test-8f4d84bbf-zbhvk   1/1     Running   0          71m
```

I wait for an hour but nothing happen

Comment: Can you please check --horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period flag value of your cluster.. Auto-scaler uses this flag to decide scaling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

**--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-downscale-delay:** The value for this option is a duration that specifies how long the autoscaler has to wait before another downscale operation can be performed after the current one has completed. The default value is 5 minutes (5m0s).

> Note: When tuning these parameter values, a cluster operator should be
>   aware of the possible consequences. If the delay (cooldown) value is
>   set too long, there could be complaints that the Horizontal Pod
>   Autoscaler is not responsive to workload changes. However, if the
>   delay value is set too short, the scale of the replicas set may keep
>   thrashing as usual.
>
> Finally, just before HPA scales the target, the scale recommendation
>   is recorded. The controller considers all recommendations within a
>   configurable window choosing the highest recommendation from within
>   that window. This value can be configured using the
>   --horizontal-pod-autoscaler-downscale-stabilization-window flag, which defaults to 5 minutes. This means that scaledowns will occur
>   gradually, smoothing out the impact of rapidly fluctuating metric
>   values.

Comment: i wait for an hour but nothing happen

Comment: maybe you have done something like -cpu-percent=1 instead of -cpu-percent=80

Comment: i write
kubectl autoscale deployment autoscale-test --cpu-percent=25 --min=1 --max=5

Comment: make it 90 instead of 25 and test again

Comment: 25 percent is very obvious , you are saying it that 25 percent cpu load is heavy load , so it thinks like that and never scales it down , until you says , no high load is actually 90 percent of cpu usage , which is not the case when load test is finished , so it scales down

Comment: but 0% of cpu is use.that is below 25%

Comment: you never know , so 25% is not a safe threshold , for autoscaling it should be above 85% :)

Comment: similar issue, I have with 25%. I don't understand why I need 85%?

Answer (score 0):

***I have used siege test method.scale up works but didnt scaled down***.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    namespace: lab
    app: traffictest
  name: traffictest
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: traffictest
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: traffictest
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "100Mi"
            cpu: "100m"
          limits:
            memory: "150Mi"
            cpu: "150m"

status: {}


**kubectl autoscale --max=5 --min=1 deployment traffictest --cpu-percent=10**

**root@k8smaster:~# kubectl get pods**
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS             AGE
lab-59f9666558-2q9tc                  1/1     Running   1 (7h7m ago)         4d19h
lab-59f9666558-7n82f                  1/1     Running   1 (7h7m ago)         4d19h
lab-59f9666558-zmqvp                  1/1     Running   1 (7h7m ago)         4d19h
lab-59f9666558-zvpc5                  1/1     Running   1 (7h7m ago)         4d19h
lab2-576ffd9654-hhch4                 1/1     Running   1 (7h7m ago)         4d19h
lab22-c8c96c58b-klhds                 1/1     Running   1 (7h7m ago)         4d7h
multiple                              2/2     Running   24 (<invalid> ago)   3d19h
multiple-container-77fd9f6878-nc5kj   1/1     Running   1 (7h7m ago)         3d19h
multiple-container-77fd9f6878-r45zd   1/1     Running   1 (7h7m ago)         3d21h
multiple-container-77fd9f6878-vgfzs   1/1     Running   1 (7h7m ago)         3d19h
nginx                                 1/1     Running   1 (7h7m ago)         4d9h
nginx-2                               1/1     Running   1 (7h7m ago)         4d9h
resource                              2/2     Running   0                    3h40m
traffictest-fc45bd5dc-2jjlj           1/1     Running   0                    33m
traffictest-fc45bd5dc-8pzcv           1/1     Running   0                    33m
traffictest-fc45bd5dc-fmckr           1/1     Running   0                    33m
traffictest-fc45bd5dc-fpzdf           1/1     Running   0                    33m
traffictest-fc45bd5dc-vbnxb           1/1     Running   0                    48m
 
**siege -q -c 5 -t 2m http://192.168.100.43:31739**

**after execution below PODs never scaled down**

traffictest-fc45bd5dc-2jjlj           1/1     Running   0                    33m
traffictest-fc45bd5dc-8pzcv           1/1     Running   0                    33m
traffictest-fc45bd5dc-fmckr           1/1     Running   0                    33m
traffictest-fc45bd5dc-fpzdf           1/1     Running   0                    33m
traffictest-fc45bd5dc-vbnxb           1/1     Running   0                    48m
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).